# How OpenMP handles array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, openmp

I am just starting playing around with OpenMp and got very confused about this problem. Say if I declare an array `int a[10]` and use it inside some loop. What is the difference between `#pragma omp parallel for private(a)` and `#pragma omp parallel for shared(a)`? To me `a` is just a pointer to the first element of the array and according to what I have read the `private` construct will make a copy of the variable for each thread, and also *very strangely* initialize it with a random value if I do not use `firstprivate` construct. So my question is if I use `private` construct, what will happen semantically? Will it make a set of pointers and assign them to every thread created or will it make a set of copies of the whole array and let each thread to use them separately?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subtle semantic difference between arrays and pointers in C and C++. An array definition like `int a[10]` provides the compiler with information both about the type and the size of the array and it (the compiler) can use that information in order to properly allocate a private copy of the same size and possibly initialise it (in the case of `firstprivate`).

`int *a` only tells the compiler the type but not the size and therefore in OpenMP such variable is treated simply as a pointer and the pointer itself is made private, not the data that it points to. If you put a pointer in a `firstprivate` clause then each thread would get a separate copy of the pointer variable but initially all copies would be pointing at the same place in memory.